# Setting up a new iPad with new Apple ID with an @icloud.com email address all works fine except FaceTime and iMessage

Tags: messages, facetime

I can sign in to iCloud, iTunes and download from iTunes so I know the Apple ID works.

I can Go in with my Apple ID and FaceTime, works fine. So I know then iPad, FaceTime, andiMessage work.

But when I use the new ID for my daughter, the screen in FaceTime or settings-FaceTime circles says, "Verifying" and just returns to sign in with no error message.

I cannot try all the reset suggestions of FaceTime as I can't sign in to activate/deactivate etc. My other daughter has FaceTime working with her @icloud.com email ID. Why does this new one not work??????

Any help is very much appreciated. I have tried resetting network settings etc. I have upgraded to latest iOS. iPad is brand new out of the box.

Comment: Could you edit the post to explain if the problem Apple ID uses security questions or has two factor authentication set up? Also, are you amenable to wiping the iPad to start over with the setup assistant? That would let you try out her iCloud account for all settings to troubleshoot. Then you would wipe it again and restore the current backup and/or set it up with split Apple ID as you wish.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I am afraid I am not an experienced apple user. We have just bought this iPad and my other daughter has one which we setup in the same way. I don't really want to keep wiping this one. What is the two factor authentication? It asks for id and password so that is what we enter.

Comment: If it is verifying, it is probably waiting for you, did you receive a email or SMS? Also be aware that as usual Apple servers are very busy, when new products come out (like the Apple Watch) so you might have to be patient and try again.

Comment: Can you turn off facetime and turn it back on, or is the switch greyed out?